# Python3.4 Dictionary value replacement issue

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have some code which takes a list of dictionaries and creates another list of dictionaries.
Each dictionary in the list has two key/value pairs "ID" and "opcode", where "opcode" is a 32 bit number.

My code needs to create a second list of dictionaries where the opcodes are separated, i.e. a dictionary with opcode=5 would become two dictionaries with opcode=1 and opcode=4.

(opcode is a 32 bit number and my requirement is that only 1 bit is high, ie opcode=1,2,4,8,16 etc)

I've simplified the problem into the following; my code needs to turn this:

```
part=[{"ID":1,"opcode":4},{"ID":2,"opcode":5},{"ID":3,"opcode":6}]
```

into this:

```
part_=[{"ID":1,"opcode":4},{"ID":2,"opcode":1},{"ID":2,"opcode":4},{"ID":3,"opcode":2},{"ID":3,"opcode":4}]
```

Currently my code is the following

```
def bit_set(theNumber,bit):
    return theNumber&(1<<bit)!=0

part=[{"ID":1,"opcode":4},{"ID":2,"opcode":5},{"ID":3,"opcode":6}]

part_=[]
for i in part:
    for j in range(32):
        if bit_set(i["opcode"],j):
            part_.append(i)
            part_[-1]["opcode"]=(1<<j)

for i in part_:
    print(i)
```

The output of the code is:

```
{'opcode': 4, 'ID': 1}
{'opcode': 1, 'ID': 2}
{'opcode': 2, 'ID': 3}
```

---

Interestingly if I modify the code slightly so that the value modification line is not there, the extra dictionaries **are** created, but obviously the opcode is not correct.

```
def bit_set(theNumber,bit):
    return theNumber&(1<<bit)!=0

part=[{"ID":1,"opcode":4},{"ID":2,"opcode":5},{"ID":3,"opcode":6}]

part_=[]
for i in part:
    for j in range(32):
        if bit_set(i["opcode"],j):
            part_.append(i)
            #part_[-1]["opcode"]=(1<<j)

for i in part_:
    print(i)
```

The output is

```
{'ID': 1, 'opcode': 4}
{'ID': 2, 'opcode': 5}
{'ID': 2, 'opcode': 5}
{'ID': 3, 'opcode': 6}
{'ID': 3, 'opcode': 6}
```

---

I can get around the issue by going about the problem a different way, but in the interest in learning what is going on I'm out of my depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused as when you append `i` to the new list you do not create a copy of the dictionary instead you add a reference to the original dictionary. This means that when you change the dictionary in the next line you also change value in `part`. This causes the loop not to match the any more parts of the opcode. You can see this if you print out the values of `part` at the end of your code.

The python documentation explains this as:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.
>   [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html)

You can fix this by creating a copy of the dictionary when you append it. This will allow you change the value without affecting the original dictionary. Python allows you to copy objects using the `copy` module ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html)).

Just import `copy` and then do `part_.append(copy.copy(i))` instead of `part_.append(i)`.

```
import copy

def bit_set(theNumber,bit):
    return theNumber&(1<<bit)!=0

part = [{"ID": 1, "opcode": 4}, {"ID": 2, "opcode": 5}, {"ID": 3, "opcode": 6}]

part_=[]
for i in part:
    for j in range(32):
        if bit_set(i["opcode"],j):
            part_.append(copy.copy(i))
            part_[-1]["opcode"]=(1<<j)

for i in part_:
    print(i)
```